# Printf not printing - returns NULL

Tags: c, printf

beginner here.  So I'm trying to write some code that take a sentence and returns the longest word.  When I debugg the program everything looks correct as I'd expect including the char array.  However when I come to print the output I invariably get a NULL...

I've put in the entire code because I think one of the loops must be effecting the array string pointer in some way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void LongestWord(char sen1[500]) {
/*
steps:
1. char pointer.  Each Byte holds array position of each space or return            value  Note space = 32 & return = 10.

2.  Once got above asses biggest word.  Biggest word stored in short int (starting position)
3.  Once got biggest word start - move to sen using strncpy
*/

char sen[500];
char *ptr = sen;
int i = 0;
int space_position[500];
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int word_size_prior_to_each_position[500];
int l = 0;
int largest = 0;
int largest_end_position = 0;
int largest_start_position =0;

memset(&sen[0], 0, 500);
memset(&space_position[0], 0, 2000);
memset(&word_size_prior_to_each_position[0], 0, 2000);


while (i < 500) { //mark out where the spaces or final return is
if ((sen1[i] == 0b00100000) ||
     (sen1[i] == 0b00001010))
        {
space_position[j] = i;
j = j+1;
}
i = i+1;
}

while (k < 500) {
 if (k == 0) {
    word_size_prior_to_each_position[k] = (space_position[k]);
 }

                    //calculate word size at each position
if ((k > 0) && (space_position[k] != 0x00)) {
    word_size_prior_to_each_position[k] = (space_position[k] -   space_position[k-1]) -1;
    }
k = k+1;
}

while (l < 500) {       //find largest start position
if (word_size_prior_to_each_position[l] > largest) {
    largest = word_size_prior_to_each_position[l];
    largest_end_position = space_position[l];
    largest_start_position = space_position[l-1];

}
l = l+1;
}

strncpy(ptr, sen1+largest_start_position+1, largest);

printf("%s", *ptr);

return 0;
}

int main(void) {
char stringcapture[500];
fgets(stringcapture, 499, stdin);
LongestWord(stringcapture);       //this grabs input and posts into the     longestword function
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s", *ptr);` doesn’t make sense when `ptr` is a `char*` (i.e. `*ptr` is a `char`). `%s` means you’re telling `printf` to expect an entire string. Your compiler should print a warning about that.

Comment: Please learn about indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function LongestWord replace

```
printf("%s", *ptr);
```

with

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

`*ptr` denotes a single character, but you want to print a string (see %s specification), so you must use `ptr` instead. It makes sense to also add a line break (\n).

Also remove the

```
return 0;
```

there, because it's a void function.

**Returning the longest word**

To return the longest word from the function as pointer to char, you can change the function signature to

```
char *LongestWord(char sen1[500])
```

Since your pointer ptr points to a local array in LongestWord it will result in a dangling reference as soon as the function returns.

Therefore you need to do sth like:

```
return strdup(ptr);
```

Then in main you can change your code to:

```
char *longest_word = LongestWord(stringcapture);
printf("%s\n", longest_word);
free(longest_word);
```

**Some more Hints**

You have a declaration

```
int space_position[500];
```

There you are calling:

```
memset(&space_position[0], 0, 2000);
```

Here you are assuming that an int is 4 bytes. That assumption leads to not-portable code.

You should rather use:

```
memset(&space_position[0], 0, sizeof(space_position));
```

You can even write:

```
memset(space_position, 0, sizeof(space_position));
```

since space_position is the address of the array anyway.

Applied to your memsets, it would look like this:

```
memset(sen, 0, sizeof(sen));
memset(space_position, 0, sizeof(space_position));
memset(word_size_prior_to_each_position, 0, sizeof(word_size_prior_to_each_position));
```

Instead of using some binary numbers for space and return, you can alternatively use the probably more readable notation of ' ' and '\n', so that you could e.g. write:

```
if ((sen1[i] == ' ') ||
    (sen1[i] == '\n'))
```

instead of

```
if ((sen1[i] == 0b00100000) ||
    (sen1[i] == 0b00001010))
```

The variable largest_end_position is assigned but never used somewhere. So it can be removed.

The following line

```
strncpy(ptr, sen1 + largest_start_position + 1, largest);
```

would omit the first letter of the word if the first word were also the longest. It seems largest_start_position is the position of the space, but in case of the first word (largest_start_position == 0) you start to copy from index 1. This special case needs to be handled.

You have a local array in main that is not initialized. 
So instead of

```
char stringcapture[500];
```

you must write

```
char stringcapture[500];
memset(stringcapture, 0, sizeof(stringcapture));
```

alternatively you could use:

```
char stringcapture[500] = {0};
```

Finally in this line:

```
largest_start_position = space_position[l - 1];
```

You access the array outside the boundaries if l==0 (space_position[-1]). So you have to write:

```
if (l > 0) {
    largest_start_position = space_position[l - 1];
}
else {
    largest_start_position = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it now returns nothing??

Comment: Currently the function signature says it is a void function. So you can't return anything. Actually the compiler shouldn't compile it. What do you want to return? The longest word or the length of the longest word?

Comment: Hi Stephen, Im trying to return (print) the longest word

Comment: You print it with the line 'printf("%s", *ptr);'. If you want to return a pointer then you need to dynamically allocate memory for it (e.g. with strdup). And change the function signature to returning a `char *`. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updates (and especially the hints).  I will have a play with the suggestions tomorrow and report back.  Thanks again

Comment: @StephanSchlecht I think you meant return a string, not a pointer. Keeping the former alive is the crucial part to keeping the latter valid.

Comment: In my answer I wrote `Since your pointer ptr points to a local array in LongestWord it will result in a dangling reference as soon as the function returns.

Therefore you need to do sth like:

return strdup(ptr);` Technically we are returning a pointer. But it must point to dynamically allocated memory (which is done here with strdup) not to a local array in the function of course. So everything is in my answer I would say.

Comment: Hi Thanks again.  I've now had chance to play a little.  I haven't worked through your comments fully (the hints - I will make notes), but when I've made the changes to move the printf back to the main function - I still get no output...
I'm using codeblocks IDE for reference

Comment: the last line in `char *LongestWord(char sen1[500])` is now `return strdup(ptr);` and in main you have `char *longest_word = LongestWord(stringcapture);
printf("%s\n", longest_word);
free(longest_word);` ?

Comment: Yep theyre the changes Ive made and I get the same result as when the printf was in the longestword function...

Comment: right so I put my code back to the way it was - just for testing.  If I put a break & debugg - to just after printf("%s", ptr); - everything works great and the printf outputs the correct word.  However if I just let it run - no output occurs...
I'm missing something fairly straight forward I think

Comment: I think it appears to be something to do with buffering and printf not printing immediatley...

Comment: did you add a \n, so instead of `printf("%s", ptr);` a `printf("%s\n", ptr);`?

Comment: ok, will take a closer look at the code and search uninitialized vars and out-of-bound accesses...

Comment: your local array stringcapture is not initialized and space_position is accessed potentially out-of-bounds, I'll added both cases to my answer

Comment: Thanks ever so much - that cracked it!  Your patience has been extremely helpful - I've learnt some important lessons & noted them down! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

While Stephan has provided you with a good answer addressing the problems you were having with your implementation of your `LongestWord` function, you may be over-complicating what your are doing to find the longest word.

To be useful, think about what you need to know when getting the longest word from a sentence. You want to know (1) what the longest word is; and (2) how many characters does it contain? You can always call `strlen` again when the function returns, but why? You will have already handled that information in the function, so you might as well make that information available back in the caller.

You can write your function in a number of ways to either return the length of the longest word, or a pointer to the longest word itself, etc. If you want to return a pointer to the longest word, you can either pass an array of sufficient size as a parameter to the function for filling within the function, or you can dynamically allocate storage within the function so that the storage survives the function return (*allocated* storage duration verses *automatic* storage duration). You can also declare an array `static` and preserve storage that way, but that will limit you to one use of the function in any one expression. If returning a pointer to the longest word, to also make the length available back in the caller, you can pass a pointer as a parameter and update the value at that address within your function making the length available back in the calling function.

So long as you are simply looking for the longest word, the longest word in the unabridged dictionary (non-medical) is 29-characters (taking 30-characters storage total), or for medical terms the longest word is 45-character (taking 46-characters total). So it may make more sense to simply pass an array to fill with the longest word as a parameter since you already know what the max-length needed will be (an array of 64-chars will suffice -- or double that to not skimp on buffer size, your call).

Rather than using multiple arrays, a simple loop and a pair of pointers is all you need to walk down your sentence buffer bracketing the beginning and end of each word to pick out the longest one. (and the benefit there, as opposed to using a `strtok`, etc. is the original sentence is left unchanged allowing it to be passed as `const char *` allowing the compiler to further optimize the code)

A `longest_word` function that passes the sentence and word to fill as parameters returning the length of the longest string is fairly straight forward to do in a single loop. Loosely referred to as a *State Loop*, where you use a simple flag to keep track of your read state, i.e. whether you are `in` a word within the sentence or whether you are in whitespace before, between or after the words in the sentence. A simple In/Out state flag.

Then you simply use a pointer `p` to locate the beginning of each word, and an end-pointer `ep` to advance down the sentence to locate the end of each word, checking for the word with the max-length as you go. You can use the `isspace()` macro provided in `ctype.h` to locate the spaces between each word.

The loop itself does nothing more than loop continually while you keep track of each pointer and then check which word is the longest by the simple pointer difference `ep - p` when the end of each word is found. If a word is longer than the previous `max`, then copy that to your longest word array and update `max` with the new max-length.

A short implementation could be similar to:

```
size_t longest_word (const char *sentence, char *word)
{
    const char *p = sentence, *ep = p;  /* pointer & end-pointer */
    size_t in = 0, max = 0;             /* in-word flag & max len */

    if (!sentence || !*sentence)        /* if NULL or empty, set word empty */
        return (*word = 0);

    for (;;) {                          /* loop continually */
        if (isspace (*ep) || !*ep) {    /* check whitespace & end of string */
            if (in) {                   /* if in-word */
                size_t len = ep - p;    /* get length */
                if (len > max) {        /* if greater than max */
                    memcpy (word, p, len);  /* copy to word */
                    word[len] = 0;      /* nul-terminate word */
                    max = len;          /* update max */
                }
                p = ep;                 /* update pointer to end-pointer */
                in = 0;                 /* zero in-word flag */
            }
            if (!*ep)                   /* if end of word, bail */
                break;
        }
        else {          /* non-space character */
            if (!in) {                  /* if not in-word */
                p = ep;                 /* update pointer to end-pointer */
                in = 1;                 /* set in-word flag */
            }
        }
        ep++;           /* advance end-pointer */
    }

    return max;         /* return max length */
}
```

A complete example taking the sentence to be read as user-input could be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXWRD   64     /* longest word size */
#define MAXC   2048     /* max characters in sentence */

size_t longest_word (const char *sentence, char *word)
{
    const char *p = sentence, *ep = p;  /* pointer & end-pointer */
    size_t in = 0, max = 0;             /* in-word flag & max len */

    if (!sentence || !*sentence)        /* if NULL or empty, set word empty */
        return (*word = 0);

    for (;;) {                          /* loop continually */
        if (isspace (*ep) || !*ep) {    /* check whitespace & end of string */
            if (in) {                   /* if in-word */
                size_t len = ep - p;    /* get length */
                if (len > max) {        /* if greater than max */
                    memcpy (word, p, len);  /* copy to word */
                    word[len] = 0;      /* nul-terminate word */
                    max = len;          /* update max */
                }
                p = ep;                 /* update pointer to end-pointer */
                in = 0;                 /* zero in-word flag */
            }
            if (!*ep)                   /* if end of word, bail */
                break;
        }
        else {          /* non-space character */
            if (!in) {                  /* if not in-word */
                p = ep;                 /* update pointer to end-pointer */
                in = 1;                 /* set in-word flag */
            }
        }
        ep++;           /* advance end-pointer */
    }

    return max;         /* return max length */
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC], word[MAXWRD];
    size_t len;

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("error: user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    len = longest_word (buf, word);

    printf ("longest: %s (%zu-chars)\n", word, len);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Entered string has 2-character leading whitespace as well as 2-characters trailing whitespace:

```
$ ./bin/longest_word
  1234 123 12 123456 1234 123456789 12345678 1 1234
longest: 123456789 (9-chars)
```

This isn't intended to be a substitute for Stephan's answer helping with the immediate issues in your implementation, rather this is an example providing you with an alternative way to think about approaching the problem. Generally the simpler you can keep any coding task, the less error prone it will be. Look it over and let me know if you have any further questions about the approach.

Comment: Thanks for this.  As soon as I get mine working above (would like to fully understand why it isn't at the minute) - I will play around with your ideas above to hopefully gain a more elegant way of attacking the problem

Comment: Sure, it is a great little exercise. Best way to understand it is to take out a pencil and piece of paper, write the sentence at the top of the page, then as you step through each loop, draw a little `p` and `ep` under the letters where each pointer is pointing. What you will see is the the pointers essentially "inch-worm" down the string, bracketing each word between the pointer and check the word length. If it is the longest seen so far, it is copied to `word` and the length saved in `max`. You can solve any parsing problem, with a pair of pointer `:)`